# Log4Net available database fields for adoappender - seems there are a few more i.e. method_name?

Tags: c#, log4net

I recently created my simple log4net database table for logging via the adonet appender.. and it works !

But then i notice another website using additional fields! Look!

Wow! i would love to know where i can get a list of available field names, for example Method_name really gets me thinking!!!

But logging normally supports adding to this field or do i need a wrapper or something?? i see via the log4net config it has the method_name point to the database field and has this

```
         "<conversionPattern value="%property{method_name}"/>"
```

which is great but how do i populate this before calling the logger?

I was using a standard Thread, logger, message and exception FIELD NAMES ....

Anybody have a recommendation or experience in what esle i can  log ... I would be great to be able to the log the method name, i am using the "LOGGER" field from GetType which gives me namespace and class...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a list of [all the different values you can put into a conversion pattern](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html).

Sounds like what you want is to use *%method* pattern:

```
<conversionPattern value="%method" />
```

You can also create custom properties and push them into the log4net context.

```
log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["custom"] = "Custom Value";

<conversionPattern value="%property{custom}" />
```

Comment: Thank Bryan, just what i needed