# Log4Net Logging Exceptions

Tags: .net, asp.net, logging, exception, log4net

I know I can log exceptions to the database using Log4Net, but I want to **break up** what it stores for **an exception** into different columns.

Does anyone know if this is available, if anyone has done this or is it just easier to log exceptions to the database manually?

Cheers
Anthony

UPDATE:

If it helps maybe use the following:

- Does anyone know if this is available?

  - These are the sort of details I am after:

    - ExceptionType
    - ExceptionMessage
    - ExceptionSource
    - ExceptionTargetSite
    - ExceptionStackTrace
- If anyone has done this?
- Is it just easier to log exceptions to the database manually?

Maybe the change in format will help.

Comment: Seriously, what are you looking for? If a Custom Appender is too hard, but AdoNet appender not granular enough, what do you want? What data do you want to break out? Based on Exception Type, or contents of the message? What problem have you had implementing your own modified version of AdoNetAppender?

Comment: what does "Is it just easier to log exceptions to the database manually?" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, you can use the approach outlined here: [Log4Net available database fields for adoappender - seems there are a few more i.e. method_name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324604/log4net-available-database-fields-for-adoappender-seems-there-are-a-few-more-i) to use custom properties in the log4net `ThreadContext` to possibly save this extra information about the exceptions in something like the following:

```
public void LogDetailedException (LogLevel level, string message, Exception exception)
{
    log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["exceptionType"] = exception.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
    // appropriate logging statement
    log4net.ThreadContent.Properties.Remove("exceptionType"); // clear it, so it's not used in future calls
}
```

And then in your pattern:

```
<conversionPattern value="%property{exceptionType}" />
```

It's worth testing/researching to see if this is thread-safe (the name would imply that it is, but it can't hurt to check). You'll also want to make sure subsequent logs don't include this data in their messages (i.e, make sure it's cleared).

(marked was wiki as this isn't specifically my answer, just a gathering of various info and discussion in the comments on [Mitch's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16076/mitch-wheat) answer).

Comment: Thanks for that. I really appreciate it. For my question this is the best answer, but I will probably turn to ELMAH for my error handling and not use Log4Net.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use something like [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/), a dodgy way might be catching all exceptions by overriding [Page.ProcessRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.processrequest.aspx) (dodgy because it is marked for infrastructure use only)

```
public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        base.ProcessRequest(context);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.ErrorFormat(e.Message); // Log exception message, or
        log.ErrorFormat(e.ToString()); // Log stack trace
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Si... This is really interesting, I hadn't heard of ELMAH before. I was trying to get Log4Net to do my exception logging and not just my logging. But ELMAH could be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

ELMAH is a great pick. A less known library is [CuttingEdge.Logging](http://logging.codeplex.com). Just as ELMAH, it allows logging the exception type, message and stack trace to a table in the database.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [AdoNetAppender Class](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.html), or that doesn't meet your needs, write your own [custom Appender](http://karlagius.com/2008/01/02/writing-a-custom-appender-for-log4net/).

Comment: Why would this be downvoted? The AdoNetAppender lets you break things up, and if you need more granularity, then you can also follow the advice for a custom appender.

Comment: AdoNetAppender class does not break out exception details.  The generic answer "custom Appender" really doesn't help answer the question.

Comment: Sam: It breaks out details of the log; what sort of details are you hiding in an exception 'message' string that you want broken into separate columns? (Seems bad to me). Nevertheless, custom appender is accurate, if not overly detailed. Does everyone need to be spoonfed?

Comment: @Sam: I don't see your better alternative answer anywhere?

Comment: @vdh_ant: if you already know the answer to your question, why ask it? Or would you like someone to write the code for you?

Comment: @Mitch: I'm sorry to say, but I guess this is just a case of agreeing to disagree. I don't know the answer hence why I asked the question. Its a little frustrating when people answer questions without reading the question (from the votes here it would appear others agree). The question states pretty much what you answered and the answer is quite generic. If you had of said No it doesn't exist, no-one has ever done this and it looks like you will need to create it yourself, then there wouldn't be a problem. But your answer doesn't really help me, maybe other people will find it more helpful.

Comment: vdh: How can one person comment on whether or not the entire population of the world has done something? Isn't it implied in the answer that, as far as researched, it doesn't exist, and you must implement it? You still haven't explained what detail you want to get from the exceptions.

Comment: "How can anyone comment..." That's my point exactly and why I asked the question. Hence the comment that states that "I don't see your better alternative answer anywhere?" doesn't mean an alternative answer is coming. Sorry I didn't get your implication from the answer - and I thank you for all the time an energy you put into looking for an answer (3 minutes), it tool me quite a bit longer to come to the same conclusion and decide to ask combined collective of the masses. I have proved the exception details you where after.

Comment: vdh: Keep in mind that me (silky) and Mitch Wheat (the provider of this answer) are different people :) Following on from your details, it looks like you can do it with the Custom Properties and AdoNetAppender as outlined in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324604/log4net-available-database-fields-for-adoappender-seems-there-are-a-few-more-i (Edit: You'll need to change how you log exceptions, obviously, and you'll need to test it a bit to ensure it doesn't get overwritten, but I think it should work; I've not tried it though).

Comment: @silky: thanks for the useful information. I know the custom properties quite well and to use these you have to manually put the data in them in the first place. As far as I know, by default it wouldn't automatically break up the exception, information. I am happy if you want to put your above comment in an answer and I will give it an up vote as its a good idea.

Comment: vdh: No, it won't manually break it out; but you'd write a custom `LogException(string Message, Exception exception)` function that would then call log4net after setting up the properties appropriately (and then your AdoNetAppender would do it's stuff to add it into relevant fields).

Comment: @silky: could you please put what you have in a different answer as I would like to discuss this more and within this answer probably isn't the best place.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, are you saying that 'cause I don't know of an existing solution to the problem I forfeit the right to point out this proposal is wrong and provide my own comments?